# How to enable VT-X/AMD-v on Google Cloud Platform VM's?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, minikube

I am trying to install Minikube on a GCP VM. I am running into an issue where the OS is complaining that VT-X/AMD-v needs to be enabled. Are there any specific instructions for setting this up on GCP?

Comment: You might just run [Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/), rather than wrestle with nested virtualization.

Answer (score 7):

[Nested Virtualization](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances) is supported on GCP and I can confirm the documentation I've linked is up to date and workable.

Quoting the 3 basic points here that you need:

- A supported OS

  - CentOS 7 with kernel version 3.10
  - Debian 9 with kernel version 4.9
  - Debian 8 with kernel version 3.16
  - RHEL 7 with kernel version 3.10
  - SLES 12.2 with kernel version 4.4
  - SLES 12.1 with kernel version 3.12
  - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with kernel version 4.4
  - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with kernel version 3.13
- Create an **image** using the special licence `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/vm-options/global/licenses/enable-vmx` (this is offered at no additional cost; it simply signals GCE that you want the feature enabled on instances using this image)

  - Create is using an already existing **disk** (for example): `gcloud compute images create nested-vm-image --source-disk disk1 --source-disk-zone us-central1-a --licenses "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/vm-options/global/licenses/enable-vmx"` (You will have to create disk1 yourself, for example by starting an instance from an OS image, and deleting the instance afterwards while keeping the boot disk)
  - Create it using an already existing **image** with (for example): `gcloud compute images create nested-vm-image --source-image=debian-10-buster-v20200326 --source-image-project=debian-cloud --licenses="https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/vm-options/global/licenses/enable-vmx"`
- Create an **instance** from a nested virtualization enabled image. Something like: `gcloud compute instances create example-nested-vm --zone us-central1-b --image nested-vm-image` . Keep in mind that you need to pick a zone that has at least Haswell CPUs.

SSH into the new instance and verify that the feature is enabled by running `grep vmx /proc/cpuinfo`. If you get any output it means that the feature is enabled successfully.

Comment: Really helpful and saved my time. Thanks.

Comment: Some the instances tries to start and then stops with no error message in logs

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://www.cloudkb.net/how-to-enable-nested-virtualization-on-google-cloud/) link. It works with a warning that environment is outdated, and a solution is given in the [warning](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment#update-guest) itself. Basically you may need to upgrade guest environment. I didn't need to do anything; it just worked great.
The answer above doesn't work, at least as of now (VM starts and then stops on its own).